# Are eigenvectors of a matrix always contained in the nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $v$ is a non-negative eigenvector of $A$, is it contained in the nullspace of A? I have an intuition that the eigenvectors for eigenvalue $\lambda$ are only in the null space of $A-\lambda I$, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

I tried justifying it by saying the eigenspace is the space of all vectors v satisfying $Av=\lambda v$. This is equivalent to $Av−\lambda v=0$ or $(A−\lambda I)v=0$. So the eigenspace of $\lambda$ is equal to the nullspace of $A−\lambda I$. If my intuition and justification are correct, then $v$ would not be in the nullspace of $A$ since it is non-negative.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Given a linear transformation $A$, an eigenvector $v$ is in the nullspace of $A$ if and only if the associated eigenvalue is $0$. To see this fix some eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. If $\lambda \neq 0$, then by definition $v$ is not in the nullspace of $A$ since $Av = \lambda v \neq 0$. On the other hand, if $\lambda = 0$ then $Av = \lambda v = 0$ so clearly $v$ is in the nullspace.

Answer (score 1):

The vector $v$ is in the nullspace of $A$ iff $Av = 0$. On the other hand, $v$ is in the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$ iff $Av = \lambda v$. Thus, it can only hold that $v$ is in the nullspace **and** in the eigenspace if $\lambda v = 0$. This only occurs if $\lambda = 0$ or $v = 0$.

Comment: Important to remember here, that while the above answer is totally true, we define eigenvectors to be non-zero, so in answering the question of if an eigenvector is always in the nullspace, we want to exclude the possibility that $v = 0$.